# установка пакетов Yii2 без composer

Tags: yii2

Сразу попрошу всех, кто советует что-то типа "не мучайся, установи композер" листать Stack дальше.

Вот [тут](https://rmcreative.ru/blog/post/kak-postavit-rasshchirenie-na-yii-2.0-bez-composer)  один из авторов Yii2 рассказал, как поставить пакет без composer'а. Вполне подробно и ясно для технического повторения и оно работает на пакетах с аналогичной структурой и не хитрым названием. Однако ввиду того, что не ясно, для чего используется каждый их файлов и не ясно где используются ключи и значения создаваемых массивов, при ручной установке отдельных пакетов возникают вопросы ибо нужно понятие вопроса, а не механическое повторение. Я выбрал пакет https://github.com/maxmind/MaxMind-DB-Reader-php, в котором надо подключить несколько классов и у которого имя нестандартное. Попробовал его установить и соответственно получил ошибку `Class 'MaxMind\Db\Reader' not found`

Я подробно опишу ход свои действий.

1. Скачал, распаковал, переименовал из "MaxMind-DB-Reader-php-master" в "MaxMind"
2. В vendor создал папку maxmind, скопировал в неё MaxMind. Получил vendor/maxmind/MaxMind/...
3. В файле autoload_psr4.php добавил

   ```
    'MaxMind\\Db\\' => array($vendorDir . '/maxmind/MaxMind/src/MaxMind/Db'),
   ```
4. В файле extensions добавил

   ```
   'maxmind-db/reader' =>
     array(
     'name' => 'maxmind-db/reader',
     'version' => '1.0.4',
     'alias' =>
       array(
       '@maxmind-db/reader' => $vendorDir . '/maxmind/MaxMind-DB-Reader/src/MaxMind/Db',
       '@maxmind-db/reader/decoder' => $vendorDir . '/maxmind/MaxMind/src/MaxMind/Db/Reader',
       '@maxmind-db/reader/invalidDatabaseException' => $vendorDir . '/maxmind/MaxMind/src/MaxMind/Db/Reader',
       '@maxmind-db/reader/metadata' => $vendorDir . '/maxmind/MaxMind/src/MaxMind/Db/Reader',
       '@maxmind-db/reader/util' => $vendorDir . '/maxmind/MaxMind/src/MaxMind/Db/Reader',
   ),
   ```

   ),

должно бы работать, но нет - Class 'MaxMind\Db\Reader' not found

Я бы попросил знающих людей объяснить по пунктам следующие вопросы:

1. Для чего нужен файл autoload_psr4.php?
2. Где потом используется ключ, созданный в utoload_psr4.php - `MaxMind\\Db\\`
3. Где потом используется ключи, созданные в extensions  - `'@maxmind-db/reader'`, `@maxmind-db/reader/decoder` и прочие.
4. Где используется основной ключ, созданный в файле extensions - `'maxmind-db/reader'`
5. Где используется значение ключа `'name'`, созданное в файле extensions - `'maxmind-db/reader'`
6. Могут ли ключ из п.4 и значение из п.5 быть разными?
7. Зачем знак @ в ключах в файле extensions ?
8. Для чего нужен файл extensions ?

Также попросил бы рассказать механику работы, например: "сначала скрипт заходит в такой то файл, берёт такое-то значение и делает то-то, затем то-то".

Если написать в каком-то другом файле `use MaxMind\Db\Reader;` то Нетбинс при клике по `Reader` переходит в класс. Понимаю, что это не аргумент, но как бы связь есть, получается. Однако в браузере ошибка.

Спасибо.

Comment: Чем вам composer не угодил? Прочитал 1 вопрос, дальше не стал, если вы ко коду не можете сказать что и зачем то вам ещё рано ставить вручную пакеты. Ну, и, пишите "надо без composer", но в тегах его ставите..

Comment: Тебе надо создать новый проект пустой. Добавить composer.json и сделать install. Потом уже расковыряешь вендор и посмотришь какие там файлы, для чего и как используются. Сразу станет все на свои места.

Comment: Но на самом деле очень странно выглядит использование керосиновой лампы, когда в доме светодиодные лампы по хлопку включаются. Это еще и опасно.

Comment: по сути вопроса есть у кого-нибудь мысли?

Answer (score 0):

Указанные в вопросе вопросы остаются открытыми, но методом тыка удалось подобрать верный вариант

```
'MaxMind\\Db\\' => array($vendorDir . '/maxmind/MaxMind/src/MaxMind/Db'),
```

и

```
'maxmind-db/reader' =>
array(
'name' => 'maxmind-db/reader',
'version' => '1.0.4',
'alias' =>
array(
    '@MaxMind/Db' => $vendorDir . '/maxmind/MaxMind/src/MaxMind/Db',
    '@MaxMind/Db/decoder' => $vendorDir . '/maxmind/MaxMind/src/MaxMind/Db/Reader',
    '@MaxMind/Db/invalidDatabaseException' => $vendorDir . '/maxmind/MaxMind/src/MaxMind/Db/Reader',
    '@MaxMind/Db/metadata' => $vendorDir . '/maxmind/MaxMind/src/MaxMind/Db/Reader',
    '@MaxMind/Db/util' => $vendorDir . '/maxmind/MaxMind/src/MaxMind/Db/Reader',
),
```

),